# How do i get the difference of elements using a single loop?

Tags: java, arrays

I need to find the factors of n =  20 and my code looks like below.

```
int n=20;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        if(n%i==0){
            System.out.println(i+" ,");

        }
       }
```

It produces the result 1,2,4,5,10,20

But ho do I find the difference of each adjacent numbers.
 Like 1-2=-1,
      2-4=-2...

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: `20!` does not fit in an `int`. You can compute two factorials using the same loop. Just loop up to the larger of the two numbers, and stop multiplying the factorial for the smaller one when `i` passes its value.

Comment: I think he means factors of n = 20?. Also this is a homework question.

Comment: @SiddarthSreeni this is not a homework question brother. I am preparing for the examination. Hope you guys will help me.

Comment: In terms of the (positive) difference between adjacent factors,  just save the previous factor and subtract from the current factor.

Comment: Write down what you'd do at each step, and then that should make it fairly obvious what your loop should look like. To get you started: for `i == 1`, you'd do nothing, for `i == 2`, you'd do `1-2=-1` (how do those numbers correspond to `i`?)

Comment: @RamakantaBisipa If you think my answer is correct. Please mark as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    /* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int n=20;
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
         if(n%i==0){
         b = i;
         if(a!=0)
                    System.out.println(a - b+" ,");
         a = i;

            }
       }
    }
```

This would print what you wanted.

Comment: Mark as answer. Pls :/

Answer (score 0):

Keep saving the last factor in a variable and subtract it when you get the next one.

```
    int n = 20;
    //1 is the factor of every no.
    //So let's assign 1 to the first variable
    int last = 1;

    for(int i=2; i<=n; i++) {
        if(n%i==0) {
            //i is the factor of n:
            System.out.print((i-last) + " ");
            //Save the this factor to use next:
            last = i;
        }
    }
```